# How do I solve this Scala function parameter type erasure error?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-erasure

I am creating a map-reduce framework, and right now I am trying to create a builder class to instantiate the processing pipeline. This builder needs to hold a list of functions specified by the user, so later it can construct the pipeline using these functions as arguments to instantiate Worker objects.

I am using case classes to create function "holders", and also for the "workers". My problem is that when I go on to analyse the holders, if I pattern-match on them the type information from the function seems to be missing due to type erasure. Here is some minimal code that appears to reproduce the problem I am having.

```
trait Holders

case class MapHolder[A, B](f: A => B) extends Holders

trait Worker

case class MapWrk[A, B](f: A => B) extends Worker

object MyTypeErasureProblem extends App {

  val myFunc = MapHolder((x: Int) => x + 10)

  def buildWorker(hh: Holders) =
    hh match {
      case MapHolder(f) => MapWrk(f)
    }

  println(buildWorker(myFunc).f(10))
}
```

The compiler error is

```
Error:(22, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : Nothing => Any
 required: A => Any
      case MapHolder(f) => MapWrk(f)
                                  ^
Error:(26, 33) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(10)
 required: Nothing
  println(buildWorker(myFunc).f(10))
                                ^
```

The problem can be solved if we define buildWorker like this:

```
def buildWorker[A,B](hh: MapHolder[A,B]) = ...
```

But I need to process different kinds of `Holders`, including

```
case class ReduceHolder[V](f: (V,V) => V) extends Holders
```

which, by the way, works just fine in a similar code, with no errors or warnings at all. In fact, only the generic type `A=>B` seems to be a problem, because the function argument becomes `Nothing`, passing around objects with other generic types work, e.g. `Tuple2[A,B]`.

This looks like a problem related to type erasure to me, but how can I go around it? I have tried to `ClassTag` all the things, but it didn't work.

**MORE INFO**
Here's an update with the approach suggested by Travis, using a `buildWorker` method inside the `Holder`.

This here works the way I needed:

```
case class DataHolder[T](f: T) {
  def buildWorker() = DataWrk[T](f)
}

case class DataWrk[T](f: T)

object MyTypeErasureProblem2 extends App {
  val pipeline = List(
    DataHolder[Int](10).buildWorker(),
    DataHolder[String]("abc").buildWorker()
  )
  val result = pipeline collect {
    case DataWrk(f: Int) => "Int data"
    case DataWrk(f: String) => "String data"
  }
  result foreach println
}
```

Output:

```
Int data
String data
```

But if we use function types, it doesn't work anymore:

```
case class MapHolder[T](f: T => T) {
  def buildWorker() = MapWrk[T](f)
}

case class MapWrk[T](f: T => T)

object MyTypeErasureProblem extends App {
  val pipeline = List(
    MapHolder[Int]((x: Int) => x + 10).buildWorker(),
    MapHolder[String]((x: String) => x + "abc").buildWorker()
  )
  val result = pipeline collect {
    case MapWrk(f: (Int => Int)) => "Int endofunction"
    case MapWrk(f: (String => String)) => "String endofunction"
  }
  result foreach println
}
```

Output:

```
Int endofunction
Int endofunction
```

When we try to match on the instantiated `Worker`s, the first `case` always matches.

Comment: Can you put an abstract `buildWorker: Workers` method on `Holders`?

Comment: I can, actually, but I don't think that solves the problem. I still need something like this `buildWorker` function to process a list of `Holder`s, but their types are already lost by the time we reach the part of the code we can call their `hh.buildWorker` method. I tried something like that, but then we have to match the holders to `MapHolder[Any,Any]`, for instance, and it seems that messes things up (I can't pattern-match the resulting `MapWkr`s later).

Comment: You don't need to match on `MapHolder`, though—its implementation of `buildWorker` can just do the right thing. If the return type of `buildWorker` is `Workers` there are no types to lose.

Comment: It seems like you need to bite the bullet and put some type parameters on your traits.

Comment: Updated my answer to cover updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add little bit type clarity to your `buildWorker` definition:

```
  def buildWorker[A, B](hh: Holders) =
    hh match {
      case MapHolder(f: (A => B)) => MapWrk(f)
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
Here few more approaches to make type-less buildWorker method:
First to use existential types, but `case holder:(MapHolder[A, B] forSome {type A; type B})` did not compile for some reason, so one attempt could be:

```
  type MapHolderGeneric = MapHolder[A, B] forSome {type A; type B}

  def buildWorker(hh: Holders):Worker = 
    hh match {
      case holder: MapHolderGeneric => MapWrk(holder.f)
    }
```

next is fairly equivalent:

```
  case holder: MapHolder[_,_] => MapWrk(holder.f)
```

Both know `Nothing` about types. So their `A` and `B` would be inferred to `Nothing` in most cases [as Travis pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29733405/how-do-i-solve-this-scala-function-parameter-type-erasure-error/29735066#comment47604106_29735066) and this is just a way to trick the compiler.

Your example code

```
   case DataWrk(f: Int) => "Int data"
   case DataWrk(f: String) => "String data"
```

could never work because types are not reified in `DataWrk` instances, so at runtime it can'be checked. But we could reify them by hand using [scala-reflect](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.1):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait Holders

case class MapHolder[T](f: T => T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) {
  def buildWorker() = MapWrk[T](f)
}

trait Worker

class MapWrk[T](val f: T => T)(implicit val tag: TypeTag[T]) extends Worker

object MapWrk {

  def apply[T](f: T => T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) = new MapWrk[T](f)

  def unapply(worker: Worker): Option[(_ => _, Type)] = worker match {
    case mapWrk: MapWrk[_] => Some((mapWrk.f, mapWrk.tag.tpe))
    case _ => None
  }
}

object MyTypeErasureProblem extends App {
  val pipeline = List(
    MapHolder[Int]((x: Int) => x + 10).buildWorker(),
    MapHolder[String]((x: String) => x + "abc").buildWorker()
  )

  val result = pipeline collect {
    case MapWrk(f, tpe) if tpe =:= typeOf[Int] => "Int endofunction"
    case MapWrk(f, tpe) if tpe =:= typeOf[String] => "String endofunction"
  }

  result foreach println
}
```

this is printing out what you've expected

more straightforward solution was just to send some implicit type to `unapply` method, and just use type parameter to specify what type we are matching here, but [this is not implemented yet](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-884), so i assume `f` inside the pattern maching could not be typed yet. But it would probably in 2.12

Comment: The problem is that Holder subclasses might have fewer type arguments, like ReduceHolder[V], or even none. In the actual problem this class models more generic commands too.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't going to work—`A` and `B` will be inferred to be `Nothing` and they're not going to be checked in that match, anyway.

Comment: @TravisBrown They will not be checked, but they will not be inferred to `Nothing`. Simple change in supplied code did eliminated compilation error.

Comment: @Odomontois If `buildWorker` is called without explicit type parameters, they will be inferred to be `Nothing` (try it), and even if type parameters are provided explicitly they won't do anything.

Comment: (Where by "try it" I mean use this in a REPL with `-Xprint:typer` turned on. The inferred type parameters for `buildWorker(myFunc)` will both be `Nothing`.)

Comment: @TravisBrown  Actually i ran [this code](https://gist.github.com/Odomontois/92232639b6dfb4c7f97f) and get `(Int,Nothing)`, so you're right only about result type `B`

Comment: In that case the fact that you're calling `.f(10)` in the same expression helps to guide the type inference. If you put an explicit type on the result you'd get both. This isn't a solution or an answer to the question, though—it's not going to work if you write `val foo = buildWorker(myFunc); ...` for example, and you're opening up the door to unnecessary runtime errors.

Comment: @TravisBrown Ok. You convinced me.

Comment: Cool, I like the implementation with the implicit tag! But in the end my real problem isn't exactly that I need to match like this. I am building Akka actors, and the actual match is somewhat different from this. And my difficulty was not understanding that `(Int=>Int)` was turning into `Funciton1[_,_]`, or something like that, which is perhaps the most classic type erasure problem, like the thousands of examples with `List[_]` and `Map[_,_]` out there. I have a different problem now, that is how  to "unpack" the type arguments to use in a constructor. Gotta study type inference!